# When geom_vline is used, meridional lines cannot extend to the border of the figure under a non-WGS 84 projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, geom-vline, geom-hline

I want the grid lines to be displayed on top of the picture, so I tried to use geom_hline/geom_vline to do this, but it turned out that the vertical lines do not extend to the northern border of the picture. Is there anything I can do to improve?

Here is the code and output picture.

```
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("tidyverse")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
usa = filter(world,admin =="United States of America")

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "lightblue",color = "black",alpha=.9) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-119, -74),
    ylim = c(22, 51),
    default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326),
    crs = st_crs("ESRI:102003"),
    expand = TRUE,
    lims_method = "box",
    label_axes = list(
      bottom = "E", top = "E",
      left = "N", right = "N"
    )) +
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
  ### adding grid lines on the top
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 90, by=5), 
             color = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(-180, 0, by=10),
             color = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 0.5         )+ 
  theme_bw()+
  theme( 
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12 ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: You have set the y limit of the co-ordinate system to not draw anything above 51 degrees of latitude. This includes `geom_vline`, which will not draw anything beyond the co-ordinate limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the y limit of the co-ordinate system to not draw anything above 51 degrees of latitude. This includes `geom_vline`, which will not draw anything beyond the co-ordinate limits.

What *can* be drawn beyond the co-ordinate limits is the panel grid. Of course, this will be plotted *under* your map. However, if the grid is in the same position, color and width as your hlines and vlines, then the lines will appear to be drawn over the map *and* continued to the edge of the map.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "lightblue",color = "black",alpha=.9) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-119, -74),
    ylim = c(22, 51),
    default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326),
    crs = st_crs("ESRI:102003"),
    expand = TRUE,
    lims_method = "box",
    label_axes = list(
      bottom = "E", top = "E",
      left = "N", right = "N"
    )) +
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +

  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 90, by=5), 
             color = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(-180, 0, by=10),
             color = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 0.5)+ 
  theme_bw()+
  theme( 
    panel.grid = element_line(colour = 'blue', size = 0.5),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12 ),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your method works perfectly when vlines and panel.gridlines are equal, but if I want more  vlines than panel.gridlines (e.g. geom_vline(xintercept=seq(-180, 0, by=5)) ), is there a better way?

Comment: @LiYupeng the grid lines are under your control, so you can always get them to match your vlines.  If you have `geom_vline(xintercept=seq(-180, 0, by=5))` then you can get the grid lines to match with `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-180, 0, by = 5))`